# Binomial distribution or probability intersection

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I flip a biased coin, p = 0.5 for getting heads. What is the probability of getting heads 8 times ?
Firstly I used probability intersection
$$
P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D \cap E \cap F \cap G \cap H) = 0.5*0.5*0.5*0.5*0.5*0.5*0.5*0.5
$$
$$
= {1\above 1pt 256}
$$

Now If i try with the Binomial distribution, I will get exactly the same result.
My question is, why should I use binomial distribution if the probability intersection is enough ?

Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Firstly if your coin is biased p can not be 0.5 . it should be greater or less than 0.5.

Comment: Use a simple tool rather than a complicated one, you will stay closer to the ground, you will stay in control. But what you did sounds good too, do it twice with "different" tools. Then the result will be twice as true.

Answer (score 1):

Binomial distribution is more general concept that can also be used in other cases. For example you can ask: "What is the probability of getting 5 heads and 3 tails in 8 flips?"

In your example you can use probability of intersection or binomial distribution. Both are correct in this example.

However be careful. Formula 
$$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_n)=P(A_1) \cdot P(A_2) \cdots P(A_n)$$
is satisfied only for mutually independent events.

Comment: But for binomial distribution, the events (trials) have to be independent too no ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.